# Java Overloaded & Overridden Function call

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, overloading, dynamic-dispatch

```
class A {
    void meth(A a) { System.out.println("A a.meth() called"); }
    void meth(D d) { System.out.println("A d.meth() called"); }
    void meth(E e) { System.out.println("A e.meth() called"); }
}

class D {}

class E extends D {}

class B extends A {
    void meth(A a) { System.out.println("B a.meth() called"); }
    void meth(B b) { System.out.println("B b.meth() called"); }
    void meth(D d) { System.out.println("B d.meth() called"); }
    void meth(E e) { System.out.println("B e.meth() called"); }
}


public class OverldOverd {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b;

        a.meth(a);    // B a.meth() called
        a.meth(b);    // B a.meth() called /*! Why? !*/
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand this line:

```
a.meth(b);
```

Here's my algorithm: a has static type A and dynamic type B, so we go down the hierarchy into class B. Also, the static type of the argument, ie. b, is B, thus it's output should have been instead:

```
B b.meth() called
```

Clearly i'm wrong. I'm trying to figure this out. Can somebody help me understand where i'm wrong? If my algorithm is wrong let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `A` doesn't have `meth(B a)`, so when you add this method to class `B` it doesn't override anything (not even `meth(A a)` from class `A`).

When you *compile* `a.meth(b)` compiler picks method which fits B argument type the most. Since `B extends A` `meth(A a)` is picked.

When you *execute* `a.meth(b)` polymoprhism (via dynamic binding) calls `meth(A a)` from actual type of object which `a` holds, which in your case is `B`. So you see `B a.meth() called`